# Tomcat Connection Count Never Decreases

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8

We're querying the Tomcat ThreadPool MBean at some interval and we see the reported connection count increase without any substantial decrease in some environments.

[image: Tomcat ThreadPool connection counts over the last week]

On other environments, we see the connection counts rise and decrease with respect to traffic which seems to be more appropriate.

[image]

We took a netstat, heap dump, and looked at the number of open file descriptors. The numbers we found while analyzing those results did not match what we see in the first graph. We have not been able to produce these symptoms in local development, the connection counts we see on local rise and fall as expected. We also have not seen any performance impact which may suggest that the MBean may be reporting an incorrect value.

Has anyone experienced this before and be able to explain what may be happening? Or provide direction as to where to investigate next? Thanks.

Comment: Did you check connection timeout values of tomcat?

Comment: @yılmaz In our server.xml, we have the connection timeout set to 20000 (20s)

Comment: It seems like there is something which keep connections alive. Did you compare server configurations of both enivronments?

Answer (score 0):

We ultimately discovered that the Nio2Endpoint may be miscounting connections. Please see our notes and patch for further details. After applying said patch, our connection count graphs increase and decrease as expected.
[image]

https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61918